# Replace a row value with previous by group in SAS

Tags: sas

[image]

Is there a way I could replace a row value to its previous row by each group? 
Below is the before and after data set. Product for each type - C needs to be changed as type - L for each customer when the ID is same it has the highest amount.

Before

```
ObsCust LINK_ID Type Product    Amount
1   1   12432   L    A         23
2   1   12432   C    B         0
3   2   23213   L    C         234
4   2   23145   L    D         25
5   2   23145   C    E         0
6   3   21311   L    F        34
7   3   21324   L    G        45
8   3   21324   L    H        35
9   3   21324   C    I        0
```

After

```
Cust LINK_ID Type   Product           Amount
1   12432    L       A                 234
1   12432    C       A                    -  
2   23213    L       C               23,212
2   23145    L       D                 335
2   23145    C       D                    -  
3   21311    L       F                 323
3   21324    L       G                2,344
3   21324    L       H                   34
3   21324    C       G                    -
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to do the following ? " Within each customer, when a type L amount is maximal it will correspond to LinkId *ID* and product *P*.  For that *ID* set all non-L types to product *P* "

Comment: Your photograph doesn't look like the text you put in your question.  Which is right?  Looks like you only want to change the PRODUCT value, not the AMOUNT value.  And you only want to change PRODUCT when AMOUNT is a hyphen, which perhaps is supposed to represent that the amount is zero?

Comment: @Richard: yes and the link ID for type L and type C should be the same for this change.

Comment: @Tom: Please consider the screenshot. The product needs to be changed only when the Link ID is the same for type L and type C, if yes, then the type C product = type L product with highest amount.

Comment: What is a group?  Is it CUST and LINK_ID?  Something else?  Are their variables you can use to sort the data to insure that the value of PRODUCT you want to remember is seen BEFORE the places where you want to reuse? Are C and L the only possible values of TYPE?  Can we use TYPE in the sort?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly, you want to have product value for C Type be the product associated with the highest amount in L Types. If this is correct one possible way is to use the following. First the product with the highest amount for L-Type within each group of customers and IDs are calculated as follows: 
note that the original dataset is assumed to be named "example".

```
proc sql;
create table L_Type as
select cust, LINK_ID, product, amount
from example
where type = 'L' and amount = max(amount)
group by cust, LINK_ID 
;
quit;
```

then product calculated above is coded for c type in the original example.

```
proc sql;
select 
    e.cust
   , e.LINK_ID
   , e.type 
   , case when e.type = 'C' then b.product end as product
   , e.amount
from example e left join L_Type b
on e.cust = b.cust and e.LINK_ID = b.LINK_ID
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple processing tasks to do:

Have you considered all the edge cases ?

- For a customer find the row(s) with the maximum amount.

  - Is one of them type L ?
  - No, do nothing
  - Yes, track the Product and LinkId as follows

    - Is there more than one 'maximal' row ?
    - No, track the Product & LinkId from the one row
    - Yes, Is there more than one Product in the rows ?

      - No, track the Product value
      - Is there more than one LinkId ?

        - No, track the LinkId
        - Yes, Which LinkIds?
        - Track all the different LinkIds
        - Track one of these: first, lowest, highest, last LinkId
      - Yes, now what ?
      - Log an error ?
      - Track **one** of the Product values because only one can be used, which one ?

        - first occurring ?
        - lowest value ?
        - highest value ?
        - last occurring ?
  - For the tracked LinkIds (there might not be any) apply the tracked Product to the rows that are type C (or perhaps type not L)